# вызов и вывод метода с свойством echo в ООП

Tags: php

Есть такая конструкция кода

```
abstract class Main
{
    protected $name = 'Main';

    public function callMe()
    {
        return $this->foo();
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        throw new Exception('Foo Not Found');
    }

    protected function getName()
    {   
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class One extends Main
{
    public function foo()
    {
        $name = $this->getName();
        echo "Hello from class ".$name."\n";
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        echo "Two";
    }
}
```

Создаю объект, и вызываю метод `callMe()`

```
 $one = new One();
 $one->callMe();
```

Но выводит она мне

```
TwoHello from class
```

а не

```
Hello from class Two
```

c return работает все норм,

```
public function getName()
{
    return "Two";
}
```

но почему echo выводит two до выражения? если оно должно как бы присваиваться переменной?

Comment: echo работают в порядке вызова, name равен null, те ничего не выводится

Comment: команда `echo` выводит значение в поток вывода. с чего вдруг указанное значение будет присваиваться переменной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo **выводит** строку. Это совсем не одно и то же, что **возвращает** строку. На самом деле echo знает о некотором месте, в которое надо направлять вывод (обычно это стандартный поток вывода). Фактически echo ведёт себя как процедура, она изменяет внешнее состояние и ничего не возвращает. Для вашего примера это означает, что сразу после вызова echo в стандартный вывод попадёт `Two` и только потом будет вызвана следующая echo и она добавит в стандартный вывод `Hello from class`. Отсюда `TwoHello from class`.

Учитывая всё вышесказанное, при разработке своих программ следует избегать вызовов echo. И сокраить работу с вводом до единственного echo.

```
class One extends Main
{
    public function foo()
    {
        $name = $this->getName();
        return "Hello from class ".$name."\n";
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return "Two";
    }
}

$one = new One();
echo $one->callMe();
```

Вызывая echo в недрах своей программы вы ничего не знаете о состоянии вывода на данный момент, и как видно из вашего примера, даже всего два `echo` могут вызвать путаницу.